# How to expand a ListView with a single TextView inside the item

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Im using a listview as i have to populate dynamically. Its like FAQs, the item shows the question and once we click on the item that particular item should expand and show a textview. I cannot use ExpandableListView as there is only one TextView inside the ListView item.

```
  Item 1           v
----------------------
  Item 2           v
----------------------
  Item 3           v
```

So if the user clicks item 2:

```
  Item 1           v
----------------------
  Item 2           ^
  This is also a dynamic text but can be put in a single textview.
----------------------
  Item 3           v
----------------------
```

Please help!

This is what I got so far!

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_faq_item, parent, false);
        }
        FAQObject faq = faqList.get(position);
        convertView.setTag(faq);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FAQObject faq = (FAQObject) view.getTag();
                if(faq.isExpanded()) {
                    view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_answer_title).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_answer_content).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_question)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,
                            android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float, 0);
                    faq.setExpanded(false);
                }else{
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_question)).setText(faq.getQuestion());
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_answer_content)).setText(faq.getAnswer());
                    view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_answer_title).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_answer_content).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_faq_question)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,
                            android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float, 0);
                    faq.setExpanded(true);
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

The list is not expanding to the full length of the text..!

Comment: You should show the code you have so far, and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Create layout with two TextView's. Set visibility to second TextView as GONE.
Implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener interface and try with the following code.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     View secondTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.second_text_view);
     int visibility = secondTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : 
View.VISIBLE;
     secondTextView.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

P.S. I haven't tested it, just giving an idea.

Comment: I almost did the same! but the item is not stretching to the size of the Text inside, its scrolling inside that item! please have a look at the code i just added to the question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a custom adapter, then you can set the extended view's visibility from `gone` to `visible` according to condition checking. This could be done in either the `getView` or `bindView` methods within the adpater. As an example, the following code looks at the previous entry and if the shop is different it makes a shop heading visible (else gone) and likewise if the aisle is different. This is encoded in the `listView's` `bindView` method:-

```
        if(prevshop != cursor.getLong(shoppinglist_shopid_offset)) {
            shophdrll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            shophdrll.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewheading));
        } else {
            shophdrll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if(prevaisle != cursor.getLong(shoppinglist_aisleid_offset)) {
            aislehdrll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            aislehdrll.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewsubheading));
        } else {
            aislehdrll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```